# Item separator in combo with model

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

I have a drop down which contains heatmaps and solid color names.  It also has a 'Custom...' option which will open a color picker when selected.  I would like to separate the 'Custom...' item from the hex colors.

[image]

When not using a model, adding a separator is easy:

```py
if self.count() > 1:
    self.insertSeparator(self.count()-1)
```

How can I insert a separator when populating the combo using a model?

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


HEATMAPS = [
    'viridis', 'inferno', 'ocean', 'hot', 'terrain', 'nipy_spectral',
]

COLORS = [
    '#ffffff', '#00ff00', '#0000ff', '#ff0000', '#ffff00',
]


class IconModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):

    def __init__(self, items=None, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        if not items:
            self._items = []
        else:
            self._items = items

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._items)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        row = index.row()

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._items[row]
        elif role == QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole:
            item = self._items[row]

            if item[0] != '#':
                return None
            else:
                h = item.lstrip('#')
                rgb = tuple(int(h[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4))

                color = QtGui.QColor(*rgb)

                pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(16, 16)
                pixmap.fill(color)
                icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)

                return icon


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    choices = [*HEATMAPS, 'Custom...', *COLORS]
    model = IconModel(choices)

    combo_box = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    combo_box.setModel(model)

    def on_current_index_changed(index):
        text = combo_box.itemText(index)
        data = combo_box.itemData(index, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
        print(index, text, data, flush=True)

    combo_box.currentIndexChanged[int].connect(on_current_index_changed)
    combo_box.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement the `setData()` and `insertRow()` method of the model since `insertSeparator()` inserts data (empty string and  null QIcon). For example you can use QStandardItemModel for this.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


HEATMAPS = [
    "viridis",
    "inferno",
    "ocean",
    "hot",
    "terrain",
    "nipy_spectral",
]

COLORS = [
    "#ffffff",
    "#00ff00",
    "#0000ff",
    "#ff0000",
    "#ffff00",
]


class ColorDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        value = index.data()
        if value.startswith("#"):
            option.features |= QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem.HasDecoration
            
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(option.decorationSize)
            pixmap.fill(QtGui.QColor(value))
            option.icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    for choice in HEATMAPS + ["Custom ..."] + COLORS :
      item = QtGui.QStandardItem(choice)
      model.appendRow(item)


    combo_box = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    combo_box.setModel(model)
    combo_box.setItemDelegate(ColorDelegate(model))
    combo_box.insertSeparator(len(HEATMAPS))
    combo_box.insertSeparator(len(HEATMAPS) + 2)

    def on_current_index_changed(index):
        text = combo_box.itemText(index)
        data = combo_box.itemData(index, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
        print(index, text, data, flush=True)

    combo_box.currentIndexChanged[int].connect(on_current_index_changed)
    combo_box.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

On the other hand, the model is not necessary since the logic of the icon can be handled by the delegate:

```py
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

combo_box = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
combo_box.addItems(HEATMAPS + ["Custom..."] + COLORS)
combo_box.setItemDelegate(ColorDelegate(combo_box))
combo_box.insertSeparator(len(HEATMAPS))
combo_box.insertSeparator(len(HEATMAPS) + 2)

def on_current_index_changed(index):
    text = combo_box.itemText(index)
    data = combo_box.itemData(index, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
    print(index, text, data, flush=True)

combo_box.currentIndexChanged[int].connect(on_current_index_changed)
combo_box.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you want to show the icon on the combobox display then a solution could modify the data method of the QStandardItemModel but a more efficient option is to create the icon and set it when the QStandardItem is created:

```py
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
for choice in HEATMAPS + ["Custom ..."]:
    item = QtGui.QStandardItem(choice)
    model.appendRow(item)

for color in COLORS:
    item = QtGui.QStandardItem(choice)
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(16, 16)
    pixmap.fill(QtGui.QColor(color))
    icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)
    item.setIcon(icon)
    model.appendRow(item)

combo_box = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
combo_box.setModel(model)
combo_box.insertSeparator(len(HEATMAPS))
combo_box.insertSeparator(len(HEATMAPS) + 2)

def on_current_index_changed(index):
    text = combo_box.itemText(index)
    data = combo_box.itemData(index, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
    print(index, text, data, flush=True)

combo_box.currentIndexChanged[int].connect(on_current_index_changed)
combo_box.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Lots of good stuff in here, thank you.  How can I get the decoration to appear in the combo display text?  The decoration is present when dropped down, but only the text shows once selected.

Answer (score 2):

If you are implementing your own model, you just need to return the literal string "separator" (or in c++ QLatin1String("separator") in the model's data() method when the role is AccessibleDescriptionRole for the row that should be a separator.

```
if role == Qt.AccessibleDescriptionRole: 
    return 'separator'
```

That is what QComboBoxDelegate looks for to decide whether to paint a separator. This also makes your combobox more accessible to screen-reader software.